# AndroidJavaObject.Call array passing error (Unity for Android)

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm working on Unity for Android application, which uses native Android plugin. Inside of it I use `AndroidJavaObject`'s `Call` method.

As it says in [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AndroidJavaObject.Call.html), signature of method is:

`public void Call(string methodName, params object[] args);`

I want to send array of strings into my project:

```
string[] strings = new string[] { "string1", "string2", ...};
myAndroidJavaObject.Call("myMethod", strings);
```

And receive it into Java code:

```
public void myMethod(String[] strings){
    // some code where I use strings
}
```

But I receive error:

`AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: no non-static method with name='myMethod' signature='(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V' in class Ljava.lang.Object;`

Can anyone describe program's behavior in this situation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Arrays require special treatment when being sent to an `AndroidJavaObject`.  Taken from [this article](http://blog.trsquarelab.com/2015/06/setting-fields-of-android-java-object.html), you can implement a function that will handle it like so:

```
private AndroidJavaObject javaArrayFromCS(string [] values) {
    AndroidJavaClass arrayClass  = new AndroidJavaClass("java.lang.reflect.Array");
    AndroidJavaObject arrayObject = arrayClass.CallStatic<AndroidJavaObject>("newInstance", new AndroidJavaClass("java.lang.String"), values.Count());
    for (int i=0; i<values.Count(); ++i) {
        arrayClass.CallStatic("set", arrayObject, i, new AndroidJavaObject("java.lang.String", values[i])));
    }

    return arrayObject;
}
```

You can then call into your function like this:

```
myAndroidJavaObject.Call("myMethod", javaArrayFromCS(strings));
```

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is cast the string array to an object, like the following code;

```
string[] strings = new string[] { "string1", "string2", ...};

myAndroidJavaObject.Call("myMethod", **(object)** strings);
```